# Javascript; splitting a string with a new line

Tags: javascript, string

I have a string that when I grab to print to a text file , It prints the string without new line after each message even though I explicitly put it in '\n' in the string. So how I'm putting together the string is as follows :

I send the message to server then I emit it back to all clients, when the data reaches the client, it grabs the text.Content and prints to a div.

```
var stringMessage= 'session\n' + '';

socket.on('output', function(data){
        if(data.length){
          //loop through all data.
              for(var x=0; x<data.length; x=x+1){
                if(data[x].sessionId == sessionId){
                  var message = document.createElement('div');
                  message.setAttribute('class','chat-message');
                  message.setAttribute('id','chat-message');
                  message.textContent = data[x].name + ': ' + data[x].message;
                  var chat_message = message.textContent;
                  stringMessage = stringMessage +'\n'+ chat_message + '\n';

                  //Append
                  messages.insertBefore(message, messages.firstChild);
                  messages.appendChild(message);
                  messages.scrollTop = messages.scrollHeight;//(message, messages.firstChild);
                }
              }
        }
});
```

Then I have a function to grab the string stringMessage that will have all the messages in the string.

```
function grabChat(){
  var hiddenElement = document.createElement('a');

  hiddenElement.href = 'data:attachment/text,' + encodeURI(stringMessage);
  hiddenElement.target = '_blank';
  hiddenElement.download = sessionId+'.txt';
  hiddenElement.click();
}
```

so If I have messages like so:
 "Andrew : Hello" 
 "Andrew : Goodbye"
and then I print the function it prints like so : 
"sessionIdAndrew : HelloAndrew : Goodbye"

how do I create a new line between all messages? I tried '\n' as you can see in the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a HTML output. Replace `\n` with `<br />`:

```
var stringMessage= 'session<br />\n' + '';
```

Else using CSS, you need to set the element's style to be:

```css
white-space: pre-wrap;
```

Comment: hmmm it seems that when i open the txt file with Notepad its on one line but when I open it with sublime text 2 they are on different lines

Comment: @AndrewONeill There's a difference between how OS renders `\n` and `\r\n`.

Comment: Windows would use `\r\n` (Carriage Return / Line Feed) while Unix Based (Linux, Mac) use just `\n` (Line Feed). So when you open it in Windows or save there, and you open it in Linux, you will see two lines. Hope you understood.